# Going through every object in program using reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I want to write a cost analysis method for a number of different classes that would count the number of times certain objects have been created. The easy way would be to increment a variable in the constructors for each of them, but I was wondering if it's possible to just go through every object currently in use using reflection?

Comment: Why not create a static int variable which keeps count? So that every time the constructor is called, you increment the variable by 1.

Comment: @RahulChowdhury Main reason is that it's a lot of manual work compared to just looping through the instances automatically. Especially since I want to be able to easily comment it out / remove it without going through dozens of classes.

Comment: I seem to get a lot of negative feedback whenever I mention it but this is a cross cutting concern IMO, perfect for [AspectJ](https://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/progguide/starting-aspectj.html).  Works for things you don't even have the source for.

Comment: @JJF Unfortunately, this is for a school project so I can only use Java itself without any extensions to the language or external tools. I actually asked my teacher about using AspectJ as I learned it in a previous class but I didn't get the go-ahead.

Answer (score 2):

Here's two ways to do this:

1. install a java agent into the JVM, which can do stuff like monitor object creation
2. create your own classloader which can delegate the actual object creation work to the default classloader, but also count objects as they're created.

Neither solution is particularly easy to implement.

I'd go for the *java agent*, because it doesn't require any changes to your application code - but is instead injected into your JVM at runtime.

**Edit:** alternatively, learn to use the Java profiler, [VisualVM](https://visualvm.github.io).

Comment: I tried doing the classloader thing where a custom class loader would load the initial class where everything starts and while that worked, any class initialized by the class would not use my custom class loader. I'll try out the agent thing tho.

Answer (score 0):

A very easy way to get this in both a snapshot and total number of instantiations is to use a profiler (we use [YourKit](https://www.yourkit.com/)). It will give you a total count for each class.

I think they have a demo and so you could get the data you want in about 5 minutes.